# Standardization of dataset into quantiles in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, normalization, preprocessor

I would like to standardize my dataset as part of preprocessing for a machine learning algorithm. Is there way using an existing packages (say sklearn.preprocessing) to put the data into buckets. I have found QuantileTransformer but that rather squishes all observations into a range of 0 to 1. I would like all of my observations to take on discrete values say 1 to 5, based on their distribution, i.e. first 20% in first bucket, second 20% in 2nd bucket etc. Maybe some combination of QuantileTransformer and pandas.qcut??

EDIT: For my future self who is going to google this problem and end up here, this works:

```
 df2=pd.qcut(df1['var1'],5, labels=False)
```

Comment: This question should probably have a `python` tag.  Also, possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31485526/how-do-i-quantize-data-in-pandas.

Comment: Good point, thanks!

Comment: This appears to do exactly what I want:
df2=pd.qcut(df1['var1'],5, labels=False)